# JSON: Filter mysql data using a mysql column (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, slim-3

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "Section 1",
      "section": [
        {
          "name": "Donut",
          "image": "https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Nicest-Android-Live-Wallpapers.png"
        }

      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Section 2",
      "section": [
        {
          "name": "Donut",
          "image": "https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Nicest-Android-Live-Wallpapers.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Section 3",
      "section": [
        {
          "name": "Donut",
          "image": "https://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Nicest-Android-Live-Wallpapers.png"
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have PHP wrriten like this:
    function getAllVideo(){

```
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM video");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($v_id,$video_image,$video_name,$category);
        $video = array();
        $action = array();
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $temp = array();

            $temp['v_id'] = $v_id;
            $temp['video_image'] = $video_image;
            $temp['video_name'] = $video_name;
            $temp['category'] = $category;

            array_push($video, $temp);        
        }        
        return $video;
    }
```

Can you please help how can I design this code? I have category column and want to sort in Json like that. Please assist.
I am using Slim-3 framework and would need a json formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you trying to create the json array at the top of your post, or are you trying to read that json data? Also, your code is accessing a database, but the field names (`$v_id`, `$video_image`, `$video_name`, `$category`) don't match the json fields to provided in your example.

Comment: Please ignore the example json. It's ust to show what I am trying to achieve. Consider "Category" in place of "Section-1,2"